# Pass file with commands to ncat and terminate the connection

Tags: command-line

I am connecting to a device with ncat and sending the SCPI commands in the .txt file. The problem is that the device executes the commands but then never breaks the connection. How can it be fixed?

I cannot use -iN flag because if I use it, connection is terminated before the command is fully executed (some commands can take around a minute to run and for some reason it is considered idle during the scan), using -wN also did not help (had no influence on the execution at all). Please note that it is not possible to improve the execution time of the commands.

The following command is used in cmd (or batch file):

```
type test.txt | ncat IP PORT
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different versions of ncat available, some of them close automatically when EOF is read, some support the "-q seconds" parameter which closes ncat after "seconds" as soon as EOF is read and some support neither of them.([Version of ncat closing automatically](http://nmap.org/ncat/))

Comment: From what I know, the last version that supported -q was from around 2013. Is there really no workaround for this with newer versions?

Comment: Isn't 7.50 the latest version?The binary I linked is version 7.50 of ncat.